# What's the difference between Q, Bluebird, and Async?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, promise, q, bluebird

I started looking into different approaches to managing a node.js application's flow, and I can't seem to find a satisfying answer to this question.

**What's the difference between Q, Bluebird, and Async and which should I be using for what purpose?**

Comment: `q` and `bluebird` are promise libraries. `async` is a utility library for asynchronous control flow that doesn't use promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q and Bluebird are promise libraries.  They add promise functionality to environments that don't have built-in promises (such as older browsers) and they add new promise features to environments that already have promises (particularly Bluebird).  Bluebird attempts to follow and augment the ES6 promise standard, while Q uses its own API.  Either of these libraries can be used to help you manage and coordinate asynchronous operations.

Async is a library for managing asynchronous operations that is not based on the use or design of promises.

I'd suggest that if deciding whether to use Async or Bluebird/Q, you first decide if you want to use promises.  If yes, you decide which library meets your needs better Bluebird or Q.  If no, then Async is your choice.

In my opinion, since promises in Javascript have been standardized in ES6, I think we will see more and more external APIs moving to promises and it will become the defacto way of interfacing with and managing asynchronous operations in many circumstances going forward.  Plus, its ability to capture and propagate asynchronous errors (including exceptions thrown in asynchronous callbacks) is really, really valuable in complex async flow.